# Add arrows to slideshow on Shopify Debut theme Products

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I hope you can help me.
[image]
I am using Debut theme and this is my product and I would like to be able to put a slideshow on my product, to change images and variant if possible when I press the arrows (which I painted by my self for the example).

```
this.settings = {
      accessibility: true,
      arrows: true,
      dots: true,
      fade: true,
      draggable: true,
      touchThreshold: 20,
      autoplay: this.autorotate,
      autoplaySpeed: autoplaySpeed,
      // eslint-disable-next-line shopify/jquery-dollar-sign-reference
      appendDots: this.$arrows,
      customPaging: function(slick, index) {
        return (
          '<a href="' +
          selectors.wrapper +
          sectionId +
          '" aria-label="' +
          loadSlideA11yString.replace('[slide_number]', index + 1) +
          '" data-slide-number="' +
          index +
          '"></a>'
        );
      }
    };
```

As I was looking for what I needed was to change the value of the arrows var(which was false) to true in my theme.js file, as you can see I already did it but I still don't see results.